# Patch executable is deleted by windows defender but the same was not deleted in earlier build patches

Tags: security, updates, patch, installshield

we have deployed software earlier and which is installed successfully and needed updates we built and installed successfully but the latest updates are being downloaded but deleted automatically by windows defender which is not happened for earlier updates built.

I want to know what makes this issue. Because the same is not occured in earlier situations. I believe some settings changed in the build system or i need to add some add on to protect from being deleted.